# Set thread amount in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

So i have a simple programm and i want to make it faster by using more threads of my pc. Here is my code:

```
from threading import Thread


array = print("Your Array:", input())
countT = print("How much threads you want to use:", int(input()))

def func1():
    for el in array:
        print(el)

process = Thread(target=func1)
process.start()
```

How i can use countT(amount of threads) in this programm? I have read about minthreads, but that's not helping me, if it was like it was perfect:

```
from threading import Thread


array = print("Your Array:", input())
countT = print("How much threads you want to use:", int(input()))

def func1():
    for el in array:
        print(el)

process = Thread(target=func1,threads = countT)
process.start()
```

Looking forward for your help!

Comment: `from threading import enumerate` and then `while len(enumerate()) > 10: time.sleep(1)` to avoid running more than 10 threads at a time (including the main thread)

Comment: i dont want to limit threads, i want to use 200 threads(for example). Like these: prntscr.com/siy81c

Comment: You know multithreading in python is limited by the global interpreter lock (GIL). If you really want to use the CPU cores, you have to go for multiprocessing.

Comment: okey, do u know a good documentation for my request?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the number of parallel threads, use a semaphore. Refer - http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects

semaphore is a variable or abstract data type that is used to control access to a common resource by multiple processes in a concurrent system such as a multiprogramming operating system; this can help you here.

```
threadLimiter = threading.BoundedSemaphore(maximumNumberOfThreads)

class EncodeThread(threading.Thread):

def run(self):
    threadLimiter.acquire()
    try:
        <your code here>
    finally:
        threadLimiter.release()
```

Start all threads at once. All but `maximumNumberOfThreads` will wait in `threadLimiter.acquire()` and a waiting thread will only continue once another thread goes through `threadLimiter.release()`

Comment: i dont want to limit threads, i want to use 200 threads(for example). Like these: prntscr.com/siy81c

Comment: It's just the same if you can understand it from different perspective. You are limiting the threads to 200 only right?